# Помогите с ошибкой в списке python

Tags: list, python-3.7

Недавно начал писать код, но выходит ошибка. Изучаю python не долго, поэтому возможно я глупый

```
Import random
class Enemy:
    def enemy_skills(self, name, health, level, weapon, armor):
        self.name = enemy_name
        self.health = enemy_hp
        self.level = enemy_lvl
        def weapon(self, health, damage):
            self.health = enemy_weapon_hp
            self.damage = enemy_weapon_dm
        def armor(self, health, plus_health):
            self.health = enemy_armor_hp
            self.plus_health = enemy_armor_pl_hp

enemy_name_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
Enemy() = random.choice(enemy_name_list)
If Enemy() = '1':
```

И так далее

> SyntaxError: can't assign to functional call

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в этой строчке кода

```
Enemy() = random.choice(enemy_name_list)
```

Поправь

```
Enemy(random.choice(enemy_name_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Первым делом нужно поправить импорт
import random


class Enemy:
    # Для инициализации обьекта есть специальный метод __init__
    def __init__(self, name, health, level, weapon, armor):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.level = level
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.armor = armor

    # Дополнительные методы не следует определять внутри других функций
    # Так как после завершения функции они просто изчезнут
    # Следует определять в теле класса
    def weapon(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def armor(self, health, plus_health):
        self.health = health
        self.plus_health = plus_health

enemy_name_list = ["Jon", "Neo", "Franklin", "Adolf", "Stif", "Python"]

# Для инициализации обьекта параметры нужно передавать в функцию инициализации
# Количество параметрод должно совпадать с количеством аргументов в определении функции
enemy_name = random.choice(enemy_name_list)
enemy_health = 100
enemy_level = 8
enemy_weapon = 'SPAS'
enemy_armor = 200

# Функция инициализации возвращает обьект
# Чтобы его использовать следует его сохранить в переменую 
my_enemy = Enemy(enemy_name, enemy_health, enemy_level, enemy_weapon, enemy_armor)


if my_enemy.name == "Neo":
    my_enemy.weapon = "Uzi"
```